# SQL aggregate function to return single value if there is only one, otherwise null

Tags: sql, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

I'm looking for the best way to achieve an aggregate function that does this:-

- If the group contains only a single repeated value, return that value
- If the group contains any nulls, then return null
- If the group contains more than one value, return null

Here's some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE
( ID  NUMBER(3),
  VAL VARCHAR2(3));

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (1,'A');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (2,'A');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (2,'B');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (3,null);
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (3,'A');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (4,'A');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (4,'A');
```

- [SQLFiddle Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6840a)

The SQL should be something like:-

```
SELECT ID, ????( VAL ) ONLY_VAL
FROM EXAMPLE 
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

The result I am after should look like this:-

```
 ID       ONLY_VAL
  1       A
  2       
  3       
  4       A
```

In the real thing, I want to do this on multiple `VAL` columns (grouped by the same `ID`).  There would be several hundred records per `ID`.

I thought this was an interesting problem  The only solution I have is a mess of NVL, MIN and MAX and it seems like there should be a neater way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for for your original data?

```
SELECT  ID, 
        CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT VAL) = 1 AND COUNT(ID) = COUNT(VAL)
             THEN MAX(VAL)
             ELSE NULL
        END ONLY_VAL
FROM    EXAMPLE
GROUP   BY ID
ORDER   BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a572b/20)